# R - hcubature and pcubature return NaN

Tags: r, integral

I have the following code:

```
library(Rdistance)
library(cubature)

fun6 <- function(x, t) {
  output8 <- log(dlnorm(t, 2.72 - x, 0.52))
  return(output8)
}

fun7 <- function(x, t) {
  output9 <- -secondDeriv(x = x, FUN = fun6, t = t)
  return(output9)
}

fun8 <- function(t, x) {
  output10 <- fun6(x = x, t = t) * fun7(x = x, t = t)
  return(output10)
}
```

Then I am trying to compute:

```
hcubature(fun8, 0, Inf, x = .02)
```

However, the result is returned as NaN. The same happens when using `pcubature`.  The return code is 0, which should indicate that there were no problems. Does anyone know how to solve this issue perhaps?